# Symfony change website's language

Tags: symfony, locale, translate, translators

I am building a website using Symfony. I am wondering how can I change the language of my website by pressing a button.
Say I have two links in the footer (English and German) and when I click any of them, the whole website and all future views I access will remember my choice of language.

There are numerous websites who have this facility and I am wondering how can I achieve this goal.

Thank you!

Comment: what you tried before ?

Comment: Did you checked [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html) about translation? Seems this is what you need

Comment: Aye. I did. I went through a huge amount of docs and in the end I found a bundle which did exactly what I wanted. It's also stupidly easy to configure. Maybe it'll help you too in the future: https://github.com/lunetics/LocaleBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/switcher.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend checking out the jms/i18n-routing-bundle. You can use buttons or links to change the locale (language) and once changed the site will remain on that language. Just a bit of advice, use the "prefix" strategy when you set it up so that your site's urls will always be domain.com/language/.....

You'll have to learn how to use the translation bundle and setup translation files as well as having to learn how to setup Twig for translations, using the translation in your services and forms, but once you get the hang of it, it is really easy but time consuming.

Comment: I managed to achieve my goal. I've checked out jms/i18n-routing-bundle and read a bit about it. And going through the docs, I managed to find another bundle which appealed to me: https://github.com/lunetics/LocaleBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/switcher.md and I used that. It was really simple. All I had to do was create a configuration for it (given in the docs) and added in twig a selector variable. Thanks for the tip (no hate for not using the bundle you recommended) :D